# Deploying latest docker containers with ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I have been trying to get ansible to deploy my containers, and I have been successful with the following config, but the problem I am running into is that it will not start the most recent version of my container.

```
- name: Deploy
  hosts: staging
  tasks:
    - name: Install docker-py
      pip: name=docker-py
    - name: Pull latest container
      raw: docker pull org/proj:latest
    - name: Stop container
      docker:
        image="org/proj:latest"
        name=proj-rails
        state=stopped
    - name: Deploy container
      docker:
        image="org/proj:latest"
        name=proj-rails
        ports=80:80
        state=running
```

I can build and push new containers to docker hub and try to pull them down. On the server `docker images` lists the latest containers:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
org/proj            latest              9f0de94df28c        2 hours ago         675.5 MB
<none>              <none>              15f4bbbeebca        2 days ago          670.6 MB
<none>              <none>              f7958247ed52        2 days ago          670.3 MB
```

My problem is that ansible keeps starting 15f4bbbeebca (which is not the latest container). Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: I believe that the problem is with the name property. The name property sets the current name of the container. Normally this name is randomly assigned <adverb>_<scientist-name>. I think that reusing the same name when starting a container has the unfortunate side effect of being tied to a image id. By not specifying the name property, I was able to start containers with the latest tag.

This observation may answer my original question, but it ended up causing more problems for me since I was not able to address containers by name since I am deploying the same container multiple time on a box.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed my issues by writing my own deployment solution and then open sourced it, https://github.com/mrinterweb/freighter

I designed freighter to be easily configurable and flexible at the same time. I hope someone finds it to be helpful. I am not finished with freighter yet, but it is usable at this point.

I realize that this does not answer the question about how to deploy docker with ansible, but I gave up on trying to deploy containers with ansible. I just did not find the ansible docker module to be mature enough, documented enough, or configurable to my needs.

Comment: instead of creating a new library to fix the problem you could have extended the docker module yourself, you're right, this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but that syntax looks odd to me.  Shouldn't it be

```
- name: Stop container
  docker:
    image: org/proj:latest
    name: proj-rails
    state: stopped
```

?

Also, why are you using raw rather than command (or shell)?

Comment: I tried using the name property of the docker module. When I use it, it works fine for the first deploy, but subsequent deploys of the container are tied to the original deploy's container id originally given that name. This means that when I want to push the latest tag of my container, the old container is the one that is started. I had to drop the name property in order for it to consistently deploy the latest tag. I am new to ansible and that is why I was using the `raw` commane. The result seems the same with shell or command for me.

Comment: I forget where on the docker site, they showed an example of breaking up a single command's arguments into multiple lines as I have in my original example. My original example works and the command arguments are interpreted. I don't believe that my problem is with the syntax. I think my problem is with how I expect the ansible docker module to work.

Comment: I'm also confused by the ansible docker module. Seems very pooly documented.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the issue arises from the *misunderstood* `latest`tag? see this https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375#.hlzfep7mn

Comment: I've moved past using ansible for my docker deployments long ago, so I won't be able to test the effectiveness of this answer.